# Fixing net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID Error in Copilot for VS Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I cannot dowload the copilot on my VS Code :

```
2023-10-16 13:52:43.335 [error] net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID: Download: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
at w.download (c:\Users\yetki\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:108:137603)
at async W.x (c:\Users\yetki\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:109:19882)
at async W.h (c:\Users\yetki\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:109:17926)
```

This code shows when I am trying from extension

When I am doing vsix load `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` giving me this eror.

I try manuel end atomatic load, but it is not working.